# Finding nearest Zip-Code Given Lat Long and List of Zip Codes w/ Lat Long

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, distance, latitude-longitude, zipcode

I have a left data frame of over 1million lat/long observations. I have another data frame (the right) of 43191 zip codes that have a central Lat/Long.

My goal is to run each row of the 1 million lat/long against the entire Zip Code data frame, take distance of each observation, then return the corresponding minimum distance zip code that goes with that minimum distance point . I want to take a loop approach since there is too much data to do a cartesian join with.

I understand this will probably be a lengthy operation but I only need to do it once. I am just trying to do it in a way that doesn't take days and won't give me a memory error.

The database with the lat/long zip codes lives here:

https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/us-zip-code-latitude-and-longitude/export/

I have tried to join the left table with the right in a cartesian setting but that creates over 50 billion rows so that isn't going to work.

Some dummy data:

```py
   import geopy.distance as gd
   import pandas as pd
   import os
   import numpy as np

    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[42.801104,-76.827879],[38.187102,-83.433917], 
   [35.973115,-83.955932]]), columns = ['Lat', 'Long'])

    for index, row in df.iterrows():

    gd.vincenty((row['Lat'], row['Long']))
```

My goal is to create the loop so that a single row on the left frame iterates over the 43000 rows in the right frame, calculate each distance and take the minimum of that result set (probably a list of some sort) then return the corresponding zip code in a new column.

I am a bit lost as I typically would just do this with a cartesian join and calculate everything in one go but I have too much data volume to do that.

Comment: check `np.linalg.norm`

Comment: @WeNYoBen Looking at the documentation. Can you give me a bit more of a lead on how this pertains to my question? Thanks

Comment: My recollection is that `vincenty` is rather slow, and I'm not sure it can be vectorized. Since you just want the closest distance, wont Haversine suffice, since you seem to have many ZIPs so the closest one should be fairly close and a small ~0.5% error shouldn't lead to a different distance ranking (as zips are far apart)?

Comment: @ALollz Yes Haversine will suffice. I didnt think there would be a difference on vectorization since at the core they are just calculations. Do you have any ideas how I can perform this one to many comparison?